# Durandal redirect during canActivate

Tags: asp.net, durandal-2.0

Using durandal 2.1.0 on an ASP.Net MVC project.
When a view is accessed I use the canActivate function to indicate whether they can access that view like so:

```
self.canActivate = function () {
        return http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/route/hasaccesstoroute?route=viewname")
            .done(function (result) {
                if (!result) {
                    app.showMessage("You do not have permissions to access this area!");
                }
            });
    };
```

This works well but what I need to do for one view is to redirect to another view and having trouble doing so.  Can anyone help how to change accordingly?  I tried navigateTo but said this was not a valid function.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out and have left the question on should anyone else need to do this:

```
return http.ajaxRequest("get", "/api/route/hasaccesstoroute?route=viewname").then(function (response) {
            if (response == true) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return { redirect: "#/viewname" };
            }
        });
```